# Serilog cannot show output logs aspnetcore 2.1 vs 2017

Tags: serilog

I am writing a few webapis using  aspnetcore core 2.1 
I would like to use serilog and I cannot find a simple example out there that works that gives me a starting point and shows me what I need to do.

I would like to do the following

- Setup Serilog in appsetting.json file
- Write to VisualStudio output windows
- Write to File location eg "C:\Logs"
- Inject logger in various controllers

  Can somebody either correct my code or point me to a link where it shows how it is used

  I have done as follows: (Copy and paste from internet)but they do not show in vs output windows

  Not sure if need all of these nugets

  - Serilog
  - Serilog.Extensions.Logging
  - Serilog.Settings.Configuration
  - Serilog.Sinks.ColoredConsole
  - Serilog.Sinks.File
  - Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile
  - serilog.Sinks.Trace

```cs
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                     .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                     .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                     .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
                     .WriteTo.Console()
                      .CreateLogger();


        Log.Verbose("This is a verbose statement");
        Log.Debug("This is a debug statement");
        Log.Information("This is a info statement");
        Log.Warning("This is a warning statement");
        Log.Error(new IndexOutOfRangeException(), "This is an error statement");
        Log.Fatal(new AggregateException(), "This is an fatal statement");
```

Appsetting file set up serilog

```json
    {
      "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "System": "Warning"
          }
        },
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "[ColoredConsole]",
            "Args": {"outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff}] {Level:u3} - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"}
          },
           "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "console",
            "Args": {"outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff}] {Level:u3} - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"}
          },
          {
            "Name": "RollingFile",
            "Args": {
              "pathFormat": "logs\\log-{Date}.log",
              "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss.fff z}] {Level:u3} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

- Nothing shows in VS OUTPUT WINDOWS
- no file is written

Where Am I going wrong?

thanks

Comment: Two of your loggers are deprecated:- ColoredConsole - `Console` and RollingFile -> `File`. As for why the config is not working, not sure - I'd try a rooted path, and I'd wire the `SelfLog` to `Trace.WriteLine` to see if any logger is reporting problems.

Comment: @RubenBartelink never used before and I am at infant stages ,is there any example anywhere on how to use it today ideally in a webapi .I dont know what a SelfLog is .I will read about it

Comment: Have not personally used in in aspnetcore so can't point to a good sample -perhaps ask in the gitter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always start by copying the sample application found [here](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http-sample-dotnet-core). It will get you a part of your way, and then what you will have to do is add the specific sinks you required.